# Add back a removed file and don't track it

Tags: git

One of our developers used `git rm config` instead of `git rm --cached config` and now every time we checkout that branch, the 'config' file is deleted. I tried this incantation to try to prevent git from deleting the file, unsuccessfully:

```sh
git add -f config
git commit -m "fixing config file issue"
git pull
git push
git rm --cached config
echo "config" >> .gitignore
git add -u
git commit -m "fixing config file issue part 2"
git push
```

How do I stop git from deleting this file from our local repos on every checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sir

```
$ git revert HEAD
[master af2e8fd] Revert "erroneous removal"
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 config
```

Also I just noticed, get `config` out of `.gitignore`! You do want to track it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to modify the commit history, then you can

```
git checkout HEAD~ config
```

where HEAD~ means the last commit in there `config` should be intact. (If not, check the HEAD~2, means the last last commit. `man gitrevisions` for complete. )

Then the `config` should be back, execute

```
git commit -m 'config issue fixed'
```

to complete.